# Dynamic XML with SQL database. How to?

Tags: php, xml

Here is the situation :

I have an image upload website. When a user uploads a photo, details like photo_id and photo_url are stored into a table called photos. To know which user has upload which photos, i have created a table called member_photos which contained the following fields, member_id, photo_id. To display the gallery, all i have to do is compare the session id with that of the member id and query the photos.

What i want is, instead of the photo url being stored on a SQL db i want it to be stored in an XML file in the following way.

```
<user>Steve</user>
      <photourl>http://localhost..</photourl>
      <photourl>http://localhost..</photourl>
      <photourl>http://localhost..</photourl>

<user>John</user>
      <photourl>http://localhost..</photourl>
      <photourl>http://localhost..</photourl>
      <photourl>http://localhost..</photourl>
```

A user can upload multiple photos but a photo belongs to only one user. One to many relationship.

I also want the php to write the data into the XML file.

Now to display the gallery for a particular user all i was doing was matching the member_id with the session's member_id and then retrieving the photo_url from the database.

What i want to do is retrive the photo urls from the XML file and display it in a table format using XSLT.

Recommendations anyone? Help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: Why "store" the XML file at all? Why not create it on demand from the db table?

Comment: What does this question have to do with XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read/write XML from PHP, try a library like [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Once you get further along and have specific questions, people on this site will be better able to help you.

Also, if you design your own XML, you'll want to

- have a single top-level element containing all the others
- group the data about each user into a single element

E.g.

```
<users>
  <user id="Steve">
    <photourl>http://localhost..</photourl>
    <photourl>http://localhost..</photourl>
  </user>

  <user id="John">
    <photourl>http://localhost..</photourl>
    <photourl>http://localhost..</photourl>
  </user>
</users>
```